# Want to use CSS transition to remove child <li> element and also move next <li> element to top of list

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, removechild

I'm trying to build a to-do list app using only Javascript (have not yet learned Jquery etc). When the user clicks the checkbox indicating the task is finished, I want the li element to fade out via CSS transition and then have the next li element jump to top of the list. What's happening now is when I use removeChild the CSS transition is ignored but the next li item jumps to the top of the list no problem. When I don't use removeChild and let the li fade out via CSS transition the next li doesn't jump to the top or just gets very wonky. How do I remove the checked li element while keeping the transition and ensuring the next li smoothly goes to the top of the list?

Here is my CSS fade effect:

```
.finished {
  animation-name: fadeaway; 
  animation-duration: 3s; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}
@keyframes fadeaway {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; 
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5; 
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is my JS code removingChild & having next li jump to top:

```
ul.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let chbx = event.target; 
  let checked = chbx.checked; 
  let divcheck = chbx.parentNode;
  if (checked) {
    divcheck.className = "finished"; 
  } 
  ul.removeChild(divcheck);
});

ul.addEventListener('change', moveup);

function moveup() {
  let divcheckjr = document.querySelector(".finished");
  let prevLIjr = divcheckjr.previousElement;
  ul.insertBefore(divcheckjr, prevLIjr);
}
```

And here is my code trying to do the same thing using the CSS transition instead of removeChild (I added a class name to the checked element to trigger the CSS)

```
ul.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let chbx = event.target; 
  let checked = chbx.checked; 
  let divcheck = chbx.parentNode;
  if (checked) {
    divcheck.className = "finished"; 
  } else {
    divcheck.className = "";
  }
);
(e) => {
  let chbx = event.target; 
  let checked = chbx.checked; 
  let divcheck = chbx.parentNode;
  let prevLI = divcheck.previousElementSibling;
  ul.insertBefore(divcheck, prevLI);
  }
});
```

Comment: This code can't even run, because it will immediately crash with an error `event is undefined`. It should be `e.target`, or `(event) =>`. Then, all you have to do is wait 3 seconds so the transition finishes, before actually removing the element : `setTimeout( () => {  /* remove the element */   }, 3000)`

Comment: Thanks!! It worked, appreciate it :)